# How to directly create a Table after using Natural Join

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datatables, mysql-workbench

I have 2 tables with Data in each Columns. I have Select the Columns that i need and have done a natural Join. I am happy with the results  know i want to put the results into a new Table with all Data and Columns.

Summary:

-First step i select the columns that i need and natural Join two Tables. I have the results that i want.
-Second step is to save the results from my first step into a new Table.

I want to save these results from my first step into a new third table which does not yet exits. Is there a possible way where i can modified my select query to create that third table with all that Data and Columns ? Can someone give me and Example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert values directly from your select

Example:

```
Insert into table_name(column1, column2)
Select select_column_1, select_column2
  from another_table
  join third_table on third_table.id = another_table.third_table
  where another_table.select_column3 > 10
```

Comment: Some platforms will automatically create the table when you do a select like this -- just be aware the new table may not have the best choice for indexes and model

Comment: So basically i have to create with another query the third Table and then insert my results. Is there an way where i can directly with less effort or modifcation of my first select query to create the new third table

Comment: @Kabaner -- yes those are often called DDL queries (for Data Definition Language)

Comment: @Kabaner  If the table does not exists you can use 

CREATE TABLE table_name SELECT * FROM another_table;